# simple proposition about homotopy group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $A$ be a topological subspace of $X$. Then we have exact sequences of homotopy groups for pair spaces:
$$
\ldots \rightarrow \pi_n(A,x_0) \xrightarrow{i_{*}} \pi_n(X,x_0) \xrightarrow{j_{*}} \pi_n(X,A;x_0) \xrightarrow{\partial} \pi_{n-1}(A,x_0) \rightarrow \ldots,
$$
Assume that there exist a homotopy $f_t:X \mapsto X$ such that $f_0 = \text{id},\ f_1(X) \subset A$. Then $j_*$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Any idea how to prove it?

Thanks.

Edit:

So, this is wrong statement. In this picture you can see a counterexample.
[image]

$f_t$ is retraction into circle around the hole. As you can see $a \not \in \text{Ker}\,j_{*}$.

So, maybe $A$ should be path-connected?

Comment: That should be $f_1(X) \subset A$, not $f_1(A) \subset X$. Don't homotopic maps induce the same homomorphisms between the groups? When $f_1(X) \subset A$, I'd think it's easy to show that $f_{1\ast} = 0$.

Comment: What does $\pi_n(X,A ; x_0)$ stand for exactly?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva $\pi_n(X,A;x_0)$ is standard notation for the $n$-th homotopy group (for $n\geq 2$ anyway) of $X$ relative to $A$. That is, elements are homotopy classes of maps $D^n\rightarrow X$ such that $\partial D^n=S^{n-1}$ is mapped in to $A$ and preserves basepoints. The base point of $D^n$ is in the boundary.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer No. I don't think so. If $f_{1*} = 0$, then $f_{1*} =\text{id}_{*} = 0$ and then $\forall \pi_i(X) = 0$.

Comment: @Gleb, try proving that $i_*$ is a surjective homomorphism. Exactness will then give you that $j_*$ is trivial. You could also show that $\partial$ is injective (which in this case may actually be easier - consider composing some map $D^n\rightarrow X\in\pi_n(X,A;x_0)$ with $f_1$).

Comment: Yeah I thought I could figure something out but I guess my algebraic topology is not good enough yet. Sorry

Comment: Yea, all this statements are equivalent. I thought that it would be easier to prove statement about $j$. Let's consider some element $a \in \pi_n(X, x_0)$ and the path $f_t(x_0)$. Then we can construct new element $b = f_t(x_0) + f_1(a) \in \pi_n(X)$ and $a = b$ (in $\pi_n(X)$). If there exist path $\gamma(t) \subset A$ such that $\gamma(t) = f_t(x_0)$ (as paths with fixed ends), then $j_{*}a = 0 $

Comment: Yeah, the subtlety seems to be that the given homotopy $f_t$ may not fix the basepoint $x_0$. Otherwise we could easily show $i$ is surjective as follows: let $[a] \in \pi_n(X, x_0)$ be represented by a map $a:S^n \to X$ and set $b=f_1\circ a: S^n \to X$, then
$H_t=f_t\circ a:S^n \times I \to X$ is a homotopy in $X$ from
 $H_0=f_0\circ a:S^n \to X$ to $H_1=f_1\circ a = b:S^n \to A \subseteq X$
and hence, IF $H_t$ preserved $x_0$ then $[a]=[b] \in \pi_n(X, x_0)$. And $b$ is in the image of $i_*$, so $i_*$ is surjective.